# ASP.NET MVC Range attribute on array

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

I have an int array in my Model. Is it possible to use the Range attribute on it in order to do client-side data validation?

I would like to do something like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Maths grade")]
[Range(1, 5, ErrorMessage = "Every grade must be between 1 and 5")]
public int[] Maths { get; set; }
```

How can I do something like this?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply the attribute to an array and get client side validation because the elements you generating in the view are of each item in the array, not the array itself The way to achieve both client and server side validation would be to have a model property for the value and apply the attribute to that property

```
public class MathModel
{
    Display(Name = "Maths grade")]
    [Range(1, 5, ErrorMessage = "The grade must be between 1 and 5")]
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

and in your main model

```
public List<MathModel> Maths { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.MathModel.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MathModel[i].Grade)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MathModel[i].Grade)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MathModel[i].Grade)
}
```